# Linearlayout manager + recyclerview: StackFromEnd(true) still showing at top instead of bottom

Tags: android

I am new to programming in androidstudio/java so I'm looking for some assistance. I'm currently trying to make an app that is similar to facebook messenger by using firebase and android studio. I'm at the stage where I am trying to create the layout for the ChatActivity (see code below). However, I'm having some issues with showing new messages at the bottom of the screen.

I have tried using ".setStackFromEnd(true);" but setting it either true or false, the text still appears at the top!  (see images)

Code:

ChatActivity is as follows:

```
public class ChatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

//Firebase variables
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUser, mDatabaseChat;
private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
private StorageReference mStorageReference;


//Recyclerview variables
private RecyclerView recyclerView;
private RecyclerViewChatAdapter mChatAdapter;



//Variables for users
private String userId,friendId,namefriend,chatId;
private CircleImageView mImageFriend;
private ArrayList<ChatObject> resultsChat = new ArrayList<>();

private Button mSendButton;
private EditText mSendText;
private TextView mNameFriend;

//Linear layout manager
private LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_chat);



    //prevent opening keyboard automatically
    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_HIDDEN);


    //Set firebase variables
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    userId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
    friendId = getIntent().getExtras().getString("friendId");
    namefriend = getIntent().getExtras().getString("friendName");
    mDatabaseUser = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Friends").child(userId).child("Friendlist").child(friendId).child("chatId");
    mDatabaseChat = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorageReference = mStorage.getReference();


    //Get findviewbyId's
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.ChatActivity_recyclerview);
    mSendButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ChatActivity_Send);
    mSendText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ChatActivity_SendText);
    mNameFriend = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ChatActivity_Name);
    mImageFriend = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.ChatActivity_ImageFriend);


    //Filling in recyclerview and adapter
    FillInRecyclerView();


    //Set name
    mNameFriend.setText("  "+namefriend);
    //set picture
    StorageReference profileRef = mStorageReference.child("profilepictures/"+friendId);
    GlideApp.with(this)
            .load(profileRef)
            .into(mImageFriend);

    //Setting database for messages
    getChatId();

    //Send message
    mSendButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            sendMessage();
        }
    });




}

private void sendMessage() {
        String sendMessageText = mSendText.getText().toString();
        if(!sendMessageText.isEmpty()){
            DatabaseReference newMessageDb = mDatabaseChat.push();
            Map newMessage = new HashMap();
            newMessage.put("createdByUser", userId);
            newMessage.put("text", sendMessageText);
            newMessageDb.setValue(newMessage);
        }
    mSendText.setText(null);
}

private void getChatId(){
    mDatabaseUser.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                chatId = dataSnapshot.getValue().toString();
                mDatabaseChat =  mDatabaseChat.child("Message").child(chatId);
                getChatMessages();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}


private void getChatMessages() {
    mDatabaseChat.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                String message = null;
                String createdByUser = null;

                if (dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue()!=null){
                    message = dataSnapshot.child("text").getValue().toString();
                }

                if (dataSnapshot.child("createdByUser").getValue()!=null){
                    createdByUser = dataSnapshot.child("createdByUser").getValue().toString();
                }


                if(message!=null && createdByUser!=null){
                    Boolean currentUserBoolean = false;
                    if(createdByUser.equals(userId)){
                        currentUserBoolean=true;
                    }

                    ChatObject newMessage = new ChatObject(message, currentUserBoolean, createdByUser);
                    resultsChat.add(0,newMessage);
                    mChatAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0);

                }


            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, @Nullable String s) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
        }
    });
}


public void FillInRecyclerView(){
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

    mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    mLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0);

    mChatAdapter = new RecyclerViewChatAdapter(ChatActivity.this, resultsChat);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mChatAdapter);


    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);


}
```

ActivityChat XML:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ChatActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ChatActivity_LinearLayoutHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/background_chatheader"
        android:paddingStart="7dp"
        android:paddingLeft="7dp"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
        android:layout_marginBottom="3dp">

        <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
            android:layout_width="45dp"
            android:layout_height="45dp"
            android:id="@+id/ChatActivity_ImageFriend"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/ChatActivity_Name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:text="Test"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|start"
        android:textSize="25sp"

        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:fontFamily="sans-serif"

      />
    </LinearLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_below="@+id/ChatActivity_LinearLayoutHeader"
        android:layout_above="@id/ChatActivity_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:overScrollMode="never"
        android:scrollbarStyle="outsideOverlay"
        >

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            app:stackFromEnd="true"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_above="@id/ChatActivity_LinearLayout"
            xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager"
            android:id="@+id/ChatActivity_recyclerview"
          >

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ChatActivity_LinearLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal">


        <EditText
            android:layout_weight="0.7"
            android:id="@+id/ChatActivity_SendText"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Type your message..."
            />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight="0.3"
            android:id="@+id/ChatActivity_Send"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="send"/>

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

Itemlayout xml file for the recyclerview:

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/Recyclerview_Parent_Container"
    >

    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/Recyclerview_ChatImage"
        android:layout_width="42dp"
        android:layout_height="42dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:visibility="invisible"
         />


    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginStart="9dp"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="6sp"
        android:id="@+id/Recyclerview_Container"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="@drawable/border_chat_bubbles"
        android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="7dp">



        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/Recyclerview_Message"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Text"
            android:textSize="18sp"

            />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

RecyclerView adapter code:

```
public class RecyclerViewChatAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerViewChatAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private List<ChatObject> chatList;
private Context context;

//Firebase
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
private String CurrentUserId;
private FirebaseStorage mStorage;
private StorageReference mStorageReference;

public RecyclerViewChatAdapter(Context context, List<ChatObject> chatList) {
    this.chatList = chatList;
    this.context = context;
}


@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(viewGroup.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recyclerview_chatlist_layout, viewGroup, false);
    ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);
    return holder;
}


@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, final int position) {


    //Firebase variables
    mStorage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    mStorageReference = mStorage.getReference();
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    CurrentUserId = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    //Setting profile picture into recyclerview
    StorageReference profileRef = mStorageReference.child("profilepictures/" + chatList.get(position).getUserid());
    GlideApp.with(context)
            .load(profileRef)
            .into(holder.mProfilepicture);


    //Setting message layout for user and friend
    holder.mMessage.setText(chatList.get(position).getMessage());
    if (chatList.get(position).getCurrentUser()) {
        holder.mParentContainer.setGravity(Gravity.END);
        holder.mMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#404040"));
        holder.mContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_chat_bubbles);
        holder.mProfilepicture.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    } else {
        holder.mParentContainer.setGravity(Gravity.START);
        holder.mMessage.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF"));
        holder.mContainer.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.border_chat_bubbles_friend);
        holder.mProfilepicture.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


        //Set picture of friend when multiple messages
        int i = 1;
        if(position+i<chatList.size()) {
            while (!chatList.get(position + i).getCurrentUser()) {
                if ((chatList.get(position + i).getCurrentUser()) == chatList.get(position).getCurrentUser()) {
                    holder.mProfilepicture.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    i++;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
                if (position + i == chatList.size()) {
                    break;
                }
            }

        }
    }

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return this.chatList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView mMessage;
    LinearLayout mContainer, mParentContainer;
    CircleImageView mProfilepicture;


    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mParentContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Recyclerview_Parent_Container);
        mMessage = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Recyclerview_Message);
        mContainer = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Recyclerview_Container);
        mProfilepicture = itemView.findViewById(R.id.Recyclerview_ChatImage);

    }
}
```

What it looks like on the emulator:

[Screenshot of emulator of what it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxIZG.png)

What I want it to look like:

[Emulator of what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jUsiG.png)

Now if I set SetStackFromEnd to true or false, I keep getting the same result as in the above picture. However, SetReverseLayout does work! What also does not work is the scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0); or any other variation, I think the issue must be linked to each other

What have I tried to do already and did not work:

- changing the position at what time "FillInRecyclerView()" method is being called, however this did not change anything.
- Various combinations of SetReverseLayout/SetStackFromEnd to true
- Setting stackfromend to true in the XML code
- Changing the RelativeLayout to a LinearLayout in 'ChatActivity.xml'
- Setting the relative layout height to match parent

Any help is welcome!

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use both setStackFromEnd and setReverseLayout. Set both value true and you will get your expected output.

```
    LinearLayoutManager mLinearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(mContext);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLinearLayoutManager);
    mLinearLayoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);
    mLinearLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for your answer, but as you can see in the code above I am already using " mLayoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);", this does indeed affect the position at which new content is added but it does not set it at the bottom of the recyclerview.